# "Used with permission" reusable in a GPLv2 derivative work?

Tags: licensing, gpl

The LICENSE file of a GPLv2 application I am modifying contains a statement saying that certain resources used in the application were "used with permission" from 3rd parties - such as textual material from a published book and certain graphics.

Question:  in my derivative work based off of this application, am I required to seek permission from those 3rd parties to use those same resources?  Or does the GPLv2 encompass the fact that the use of these resources was already permitted in the original work, and thus the 3rd-party permission "flows through" to my derivative work?

Answer (score 4):

"With permission" can mean anything. It can mean "Permission to license under GPLv2" or "Permission for me to distribute them together with my GPLv2 application, but not for anyone else". When the license file doesn't make clear what kind of permission the author has, it isn't clear which license these resources are under. You should contact the author.

When the assets are not GPL and the application does not work without these assets, the GPLv2 is void and the author should choose a different license. Section 7 of [the GPLv2](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html) says:

> If you cannot distribute so as to satisfy simultaneously your obligations under this License and any other pertinent obligations, then as a consequence **you may not distribute the Program at all**.

Comment: Doesn't that mean I can grab an Open source module of compatible license and just say "with permission" about it's inclusion?

Comment: @ratchetfreak That depends on what you are going to do with the resulting work and who gave you the permission *for what* and to *do what*.

Comment: Isn't the license implicit permission?

Comment: @ratchetfreak Sorry, but I don't understand what point you are trying to make.

Comment: @Philipp Are you saying that, if the 3rd party permitted assets are not GPL, then the original application author (not referring to me, the derived work author) should not have released their application as GPLv2 to begin with?

Comment: @JGMiller Yes, that is what I want to say.

Answer (score 1):

You received the application under the distribution terms of GPLv2.  Those are the only terms that apply to you.  If the party who gave it to you didn't have the right to distribute some of it, that's their problem, not yours.  Your responsibility is to honor the GPL restrictions, plus any other restrictions laid upon you in the license you received.  As long as the license doesn't restrict your use of those files, they're covered by the GPL.

Comment: Yup. There is _never_ any requirement to 'look through' a licence if all you want to do is use what it offers and you are prepared to abide by its terms.